# button to draw line vb.net not working?

Tags: vb.net, button, line, draw

I’m trying to create a line using a button which isn’t working.

If I use the following code,

```
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D
Imports System.Windows.Forms

  Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)
      Dim g As Graphics = e.Graphics
      Dim pn As New Pen(Color.Blue)
      Dim pt1 As New Point(30, 30)
      Dim pt2 As New Point(110, 100)
      g.DrawLine(pn, pt1, pt2)
End sub
```

It works perfectly, but if I want to only draw after a button is clicked such as,

```
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D
Imports System.Windows.Forms

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

      Dim g As Graphics = e.Graphics
      Dim pn As New Pen(Color.Blue)
      Dim pt1 As New Point(30, 30)
      Dim pt2 As New Point(110, 100)
      g.DrawLine(pn, pt1, pt2)

    End Sub
```

It says “’Graphics’ is not a member of ‘System.EventArgs’.???

I also tried changing:

```
   Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
```

To:

```
   Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As graphics.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
```

And a few simular variations (to many to list) but I get alsorts of error responses.

So how do you draw a line with the click of a button using e.graphics???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a reference to the Graphics context of your form (I am assuming WinForms here).

The simplest way for you would be to add this line at the top of the button click:

```
Dim g As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics
```

Drawing graphics is more complex than this because you should really persist what you are drawing into memory and re-draw it as necessary when the `OnPaint` event fires if what you have drawn is contained within the `e.ClipRectangle` property of the `PaintEventArgs`, but the code line above should get you started for now.

Answer (score 0):

The two events you are using have diffrent EventArgs. The Click EventArgs has informations about the click and the PaintEventArgs about informations what to paint.

You can invoke to repaint the button and use your onPaint method. This is a good programming style. Pair the event with corresponding content. paint to paint. click to click.

```
Private drawLine as boolean = false

Private Sub Button1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Button1.Paint
  If drawLine then
    Dim g As Graphics = e.Graphics
    Dim pn As New Pen(Color.Blue)
    Dim pt1 As New Point(30, 30)
    Dim pt2 As New Point(110, 100)
    g.DrawLine(pn, pt1, pt2)
  End if
End sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  drawLine = true
  Button1.refresh()
End Sub
```